# ruby mysql connection error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using MySQL and ruby 1.8.6. I want to connect to MySQL so for that I am using active record gem. My code is

```
def initialize

    @db_adapter  = "mysql2"
    @db_host     = "localhost"
    @db_database = "database_name"
    @db_user     = "root"
    @db_password = "root123"
    con = nil

end

def database_connection
           con = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(  
              :adapter  => $db_adapter,  
              :host     => $db_host,  
              :database => $db_database,
              :user     => $db_user,
              :password => $db_password  
           )

           return con
end
```

but when i am tring to connect it's giving me this error

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:76:in `establish_connection': Please install the  adapter: `gem install activerecord--adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/_adapter) (RuntimeError)
    from /cmf/samnew/build/Controller/databaseConnection.rb:32:in `database_connection'
    from controller.rb:23
```

Comment: run gem install activerecord-adapter  and try again

Comment: Note that @instance_variables aren't the same thing at all as $global_variables.

Answer (score 3):

The error shows the `activerecord--adapter` gem is not installed. You can install the gem using the command

```
gem install activerecord--adapter.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
con = ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(  

        :adapter  => @db_adapter,  

        :host     => @db_host,  

        :database => @db_database,

        :user     => @db_user,

        :password => @db_password  

)
```

Comment: Print your variable $db_adapter in database_connection function, I think that you need variable @db_adapter.